# How to disable a single menu item?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, menu, webix

Apparently I have another Webix question.

I'm trying to disable a single menu item, but the `onItemClick` action for submenu is still works. Here's my code:

```
webix.ui({
  view:"menu", 
  id:'menu', 
  data:[
    { 
      id:'root',
      value:'Available actions',    
      config:{ 
        on: { 
          onItemClick: function(id){ webix.message(id) }
        }
      },
      submenu:[
       { id:'1', value:'Open...' }
     ]
    }
  ]
});

$$('menu').disableItem('1');
```

Full sample: http://webix.com/snippet/9128f7b0

Where I was wrong and is there any way to disable menu item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `onItemClick` to `onMenuItemClick`.

Example: http://webix.com/snippet/8cba874c

From [Webix docs](http://docs.webix.com/desktop__menu.html):

> Both methods can be used in either of menu inner events, for instance, click events:
>   onMenuItemClick - fires on clicking all menu items regardless of hierarchy level. Ignores disabled items;
>   onItemClick - standard event that fires on clicking any item of the same hierarchy level. Fires for disabled item as well.

Comment: Thanks! One important correction - seems like `onMenuItemClick` should be defined for the menu, not for its item: http://webix.com/snippet/da63bc2b

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log($$('menu').disableItem)
```

logs here

> function (t) {this.getMenu(t).addCss(t,"webix_disabled");}

```
console.log($$('menu').getMenu)
```

logs here

> function (t) {if(this.data.pull[t])return this;for(var e in this.data.pull){var i=this.getItem(e);if(i.submenu){var s=this.br(i).getMenu(t);if(s)return s}}}

```
$$('menu').disableItem('1');   // only add disabled class for id=1
```

you can filter id === '1' onclick by

> onItemClick: function(id){ if(id !== '1'){// code here}}

or change **onItemClick** 2 **onMenuItemClick**

`follow the #1 answer`

Comment: > _only add disabled class for id=1_

Thank you for the explanation! AFAICS `onMenuItemClick` handles it just as needed